# How to loop MySql subquery result?

Tags: mysql, sql

There are 4 entities: Tag, Question, a join table between them - Question_Has_Tag and the last one is Related_Tag, which has two fields besides id: main_tag and child_tag. Bouth are references to Tag.id

Subquery returns more than one result and I need to loop it, but don't know how

```
select t.id, t.name, count(question_has_tag.tag_id) as i from tag as t
   join question_has_tag on t.id = question_has_tag.tag_id
   where t.id = 
     (select related_tag.child_tag from related_tag
     join tag as t on related_tag.main_tag = t.id
     where related_tag.main_tag = 1)
   group by t.id order by i desc;
```

Comment: Not `WHERE .. = (..)` but `WHERE .. IN (..)`. But the best way is to rewrite this to JOIN. PS. ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over a  subquery result in SQL is not possible  ..  you can use loop in a procedural language eg: server side language on using trigger  ..

anyway in your case you could use a join instead of a comparision with the subqiery result

```
select t.id, t.name, count(question_has_tag.tag_id) as i 
from tag as t
join question_has_tag on t.id = question_has_tag.tag_id
INNER JOIN  (
    select related_tag.child_tag from related_tag
     join tag as t on related_tag.main_tag = t.id
     where related_tag.main_tag = 1
) t2 t.id = t2.child_tag 
group by t.id order by i desc;
```

or if you need just a result limit the result

```
select t.id, t.name, count(question_has_tag.tag_id) as i 
from tag as t
join question_has_tag on t.id = question_has_tag.tag_id
where t.id =       (
    select related_tag.child_tag from related_tag
     join tag as t on related_tag.main_tag = t.id
     where related_tag.main_tag = 1
     ORDER BY child_tag 
     limit 1
)
group by t.id order by i desc;
```

or also use a IN clause instead of  =

```
select t.id, t.name, count(question_has_tag.tag_id) as i 
from tag as t
join question_has_tag on t.id = question_has_tag.tag_id
where t.id IN      (
    select related_tag.child_tag from related_tag
     join tag as t on related_tag.main_tag = t.id
     where related_tag.main_tag = 1
)
group by t.id order by i desc;
```

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless